# How to migrate Liferay portal from one windows machine to other?

Tags: liferay

Liferay migration from one server to another help required. Can anyone share there steps for migration of Liferay portal 5.2.3 from one server to another. I am using Windows + Tomcat + MySql.

I have uploaded whole tomcat folder to the new windows machine and imported the database too with the corresponding change to the configuration file like Database details.

But after starting the tomcat server it is showing some error like "Unable to load repository http://plugins.liferay.com". Any idea why I am getting this error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the steps that I have followed and able to migrate the Liferay successfully:

1. Take the backup of Liferay files and database from first windows machine.
2. Install the same version of Liferay (Say Liferay 5.2.3) on second windows machine.
3. Shut down Liferay.
4. Import the database on new system.
5. Add portal-ext.properties with relevant entries. (e.g Datbase Name, User Name , Pasword etc)
6. Add \liferay-portal-5.2.3\data\document_library  files from old machine.
7. Start the tomcat. It will automtically do the rest.

NOTE: In the above method I have not deployed Theme and custom plugins etc, you have to deploy Theme and custom plugins also that are used on old system.

Comment: Hi.. i did almost the same. I copied the entire folder of liferay from my system to a virtual machine. I changed the Liferay.home path in the properties file. I am using Lifery's default database. I also faced the same problem of losing the data and deal with a fresh portal. Can you help me?

Comment: For debugging  you can take copy of entire liferay folder to new machine and keep same folder structure in source and destination server and then import database. If this is working you can change other configuration settings later.

Answer (score 0):

Lifery is trying to connect to plugin repository to find whether there are updates for plugins. 
Does your new machine have internet conectivity?

Also you have options to ignore that message or configure liferay not to check for updates.
For later put in portal-ext.properties

```
plugin.repositories.trusted=
plugin.repositories.untrusted=
```

UPDATE:

If behind proxy create (if not existent) system-ext.properties (beside portal-ext.properties) and add

```
com.liferay.util.Http.proxy.host=proxy_host
com.liferay.util.Http.proxy.port=proxy_port
```

Change proxy_host and proxy_port with your values.

Also remove from portal-ext.properties if you want liferay to check repositories

```
plugin.repositories.trusted=
plugin.repositories.untrusted=
```

Comment: Thanks Martin for your reply. So, Can I add the following:               plugin.repositories.trusted= False
plugin.repositories.untrusted= False.                                       Internet is connected to my PC so if I put the above lines in portal-ext.properties then it may be not check for updates right ?

Comment: You should not put ...=False, you should put exactly as it is stated above. And yes if you put it Liferay will not be able to check for updates. If you have connection on that machine is it behind a proxy?

Comment: Even after adding the above mentioned properties to portal-ext.properties still the same ERROR  like "Unable to load repository http://plugins.liferay.com" and WARN like "Unable to communicate  repository http://plugins.liferay.com".                                      And yes my machine is behind the proxy. Any suggestion how I can resolve error and warning ?

Comment: Even after the above mentioned changes again the same problem. Even I have tried the method posted on by Hector Perez https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/1410886 but not able to solve the problem.    
 Please check link for the log file: http://anotepad.com/notes/1805023

Comment: Did you create keystore? Or at least tried to copy "C:\Documents and Settings\sunilkr\.mykeystore" from old machine to same location on new one?

Comment: I am able to remove that error. As I am configuring liferay on my localhost I dont want to enable SSL so I have removed the line "keystoreFile="${user.home}/.mykeystore" keystorePass="XXXXXXXXXX" from the file tomcat/conf/server.xml and also I was getting "Error importing LDAP users and groups" so I tried with  http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/LDAP link. Can you suggest me how can I set LDAP details in database table "portletpreferences" so that I can easily setup on my localhost as per "http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/LDAP" for localhost?

Comment: Finally able to do it successfully. I have used fresh installation of the liferay and after that configure with the old MYSQL database with http://mahipalrana.blogspot.in/2009/10/configure-mysql-for-liferay-523.html instruction. Thanks Martin for your great support.